# Prove an expression with summation using mathematical induction

Tags: summation, induction, recurrence-relations

We have an iterative formula:
$h_{t} = 2*h_{t-1} + 2 * \sum_{i=1}^{t-1}a_{i}b_{i} + 2 * \sum_{j=1}^{t}c_{i}d_{i} + t$.

Suppose we start with $h_1$, and $h_1 = 0$. 
I want to know how I can find a general formula for the variable $h$ by mathematical induction. 
I wish I could get something like this: $h_{t} = \sum_{i=1}^{t}(\text{equations})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient of $a_1b_1$ in:

- $h_1$ is 0
- $h_2$ is 2
- $h_3$ is 6
- $h_4$ is 14

Thus you can see that the coefficient of $a_1b_1$ in $h_t$ is $2^t-2$.

This makes the approach clear: Find the coefficient of each $a_ib_i$ and each $c_jd_j$ in $h_t$ by pattern observation like I did above, and then prove it by mathematical induction.

For the constant, the sequence is $0, 2, 7, 18, 41, 88,\cdots$ 
The difference of difference of this sequence is $3, 6, 12, 24 \cdots$ 
Use this to get the general formula.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I also looked for the law of $a_ib_i$ coefficient at the beginning, but I am not sure whether this way of thinking is a good way to find the law.

Comment: @stochastic20 why not? That's the general approach...